# Is removing the main view sufficient or do I need to remove each subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

When opening the app I am creating a `backgroundView` and adding 3 different subviews into the `backgroundView`.

When I press the Cancel button, I need to remove everything. For that, do I have to remove each of the subviews or I can remove only `backgroundView`?

```
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
[backgroundView addSubview:reportView];
[backgroundView addSubview:nameView];
[backgroundView addSubview:labelView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to remove the background view.
All views nested within it are also removed by that.